# Cassandra cqlsh unable to login non-superusers

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql, cqlsh

Followed [this](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-dse/datastax_enterprise/unifiedAuth/configAuthenticate.html) procedure to enable DSE authentication and authorization.

`cqlsh` is able to login super users, but unable to login normal users(superuser=false).

Below is the error when tried to login a normal user:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)})
```

It was also able to login `cassandra` superuser.

Below is the description of `system_auth` keyspace:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;

cassandra@cqlsh> show version;
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 | DSE 5.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
cassandra@cqlsh>
```

I am running cassandra locally on my ubuntu box. Please help me out with the error.

**EDIT - 03/24/2017**

Running Cassandra on 1 node (Ubuntu). The version details of DSE, Cassandra, CQL are above.

```
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: dc1
===============
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1   1.3 MB     32           ?       aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  rack1
```

I created users like this as per documentation:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> create role krishna with password='krishna' and login=true;
cassandra@cqlsh> list roles        **(This gave me expected output, krishna is not superuser)**
cassandra@cqlsh> login krishna
Password: 
'Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)}
```

I also tried logging in using cqlsh:

```
$ cqlsh -u krishna -p krishna
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': AuthenticationFailed('Failed to authenticate to 127.0.0.1: Error from server: code=0100 [Bad credentials] message="Failed to login. Please re-try."',)})
```

The same worked when I created a super user:

```
cassandra@cqlsh> create role superuser with password='superuser' and login=true and superuser=true;
cassandra@cqlsh> login superuser 
Password: 
superuser@cqlsh>                 **(Logged in correctly)**
```

Also with cqlsh:

```
$ cqlsh -u superuser -p superuser
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.9.1346 | DSE 5.0.3 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
superuser@cqlsh
```

Comment: The error says bad credentials, you have attached the link which you followed, but also attach the code how you created users, grant permissions and increased replications options of your system_auth and your cluster information

Comment: @Shoban Sundar Added the edit describing what you needed.